# how to install cakephp on shared host?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

i already setup on localhost (wampserver) and it is work correctly but when upload my project on web hosting i dont know how to configure and setup cakephp 1.3 on the host.
when i log into ftp i see this folders

```
/public_html
/DO_NOT_UPLOAD_HERE
```

so i put my files here

```
/public_html/myproject/app
/public_html/myproject/cake
/public_html/myproject/vendors
/public_html/myproject/.htaccess
/public_html/myproject/index.php
```

but when request site i see 4.4 error...

also i see this tutorial [link](http://www.cakephp.co.uk/installing_cakephp_on_cpanel_server.html) but i am not sure it is work on 1.3 version or just on 1.2 ..so please someone explain by Specific steps how to setup cakephp 1.3 on the host

Comment: What is a 4.4 error? And have you tried actually reading the cookbook and following the blog tutorial? That was put there to train developers who are new to CakePHP and should answer all of your basic questions, including this one.

Comment: Lèse majesté ...i dont see tutorial on cookbook to explain correctly how to configure cakephp on sharehost..on the other side i put this blog link to ask is this steps work on 1.3 or not..but you dont answer the first or the second question..so thanks

Comment: Then you haven't looked carefully enough. There are sections in each version of the cookbook dedicated to configurations for different setups. And you haven't asked any specific questions (nor answered what a 4.4 error is). All you've asked is for someone to basically copy the entire installation and configuration sections of the cookbook for you.

Comment: i follow this steps book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/914/Production and removed /public_html but when request (homepage ) alashera.3owl.com i see Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server. Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Did you follow all the steps (including the part about changing document root to `/cake_install/app/webroot`)?

Comment: yes..i removed html_public and add  all myproject folder like this /dvdcake/app                                                          /dvdcake/cake                                                  /dvdcake/vendors                                                 /dvdcake/.htaccess                                             /dvdcake/index.php

Comment: You still need to change your docroot from your web host's control panel. If you didn't change it from `/public_html`, then the web server is going to keep looking for `/public_html` to serve your web pages from. If it doesn't find it, it'll likely give an error. So log into your web host's cpanel or whatever, and [find a screen like this](http://drupal.org/files/cpanel1.png). Change the `/public_html` to `/dvdcake/app/webroot`.

Comment: please see this image..you mean this page ?? http://www3.0zz0.com/2012/01/29/05/128531112.jpg

Comment: but when i change it to /home/u560489163/tet/app/webroot i see this error     '/home/u560489163/tet/app/webroot' contains characters which are non alphabetic and no digits

Comment: Sorry, that might not be the field. See this page: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/AddonDomains

Comment: Did you mean this? http://www8.0zz0.com/2012/01/29/16/511366230.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Check out this link: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/908/Requirements
You have a sidebar to your left , this is the cookbook for 1.3 , It's in English and It's simple , good luck.

Comment: thanks ofir..but i still miss understanding more things..for example..i dont know what is DocumentRoot directive how to find it in the control panel and how to change it to DocumentRoot /cake_install/app/webroot..

Comment: i follow this steps http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/914/Production and removed /public_html but when request (homepage ) http://alashera.3owl.com/ i see Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: you shouldn't remove public_html folder. Try to  recover it or contact your hosting provider to do so. Check that your server can host cakephp (requirements).